# Regex - Capturing Macs; Enforcing match length & Removing middle matches

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to capture MACs, but I'm doing so from manual human inputs with a variety of ways they entered in values. To this end I want to caputre only the actual values (such as AABBCCDDEEFF) without seperators, and then insert the seperators myself.

Currently my regex is:

```
([0-9A-F]{2,12}(?:[:.,]?)(?: ?)){1,5}([0-9A-F]{2,4})(?:$| )
```

Given the sample of:

```
AABBCCDD11AA
AABB.CCDD.11AA
AB.BB.CC.DD.11.AA
AA.BB.CC.DD.11:AA   uselessText
UselessText AA.BB.CC.DD.11.AA   
MoreText:AA,BB:CC.DD.11.AA
AA. BB. CC. DD. 11. AA
AA, BB, CC, DD, 11, AA   uselessText
UselessText.:AA:BB:CC:DD: 11: AA
MoreText:00.AA.BB.CC.DD.11.AA
Text00.00.00.00.00.00
ABAB 
There's nothing to match on this line
01010101010 textUslessText
```

It does pick up MACs, but it also picks up invalid values including "ABAB " and "01010101010 ". Further it's still appears to be selecting : . and/or , for the value seperators, and it's picking up terminating whitespace despite (?:$| ).

So my question actually has three parts:

1. How do I enforce final matches of exactly X characters?
2. Why is this still selecting characters inside (?:...)?
3. Why is the terminating whitespace being selected?

I've never become comfortable with Regex, so it might be something obvious that I'm overlooking.

Comment: I think perhaps the approach could be improved. Maybe grouping the data and separators together, then specifying that there must be 5 * ((2 * hex digits) followed by 0 or 1 separators) followed by 2 hex digits would work better.

Comment: @EricFinn: That doesn't cover the second sample case, where there's 3 hex digits before a seperator, though, does it?

Comment: Who writes MACs like that? It's generally okay to tell a human who entered something formatted oddly "I can't understand that". Would you expect to be able to enter a phone number as "12 3-4-(567)-89"? Also, your second sample case has 4 hex digits before the separator, not 3.

Comment: @EricFinn: Erm, you're right about the 4 vs 3. And I'm trying to parse through tens of thousands of historic human-written records, and pull out MACs to match them up with live discovery. Hopefully this effort will remove problems like these, but until then this is what I have. I can do everything with ~3 Regex expressions and some other code tricks, but the solution is messy, and slow. I was hoping to translate it to just Regex.

Answer (score 1):

A messy problem may deserve an inelegant, or at least repetitive, regular expression.  If the expression `([0-9A-F]{2})` matches one byte of the MAC address and `(?:[:., ]*)` matches permissible separators including space, then the fully expanded regular expression for a MAC address is

```
([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})
```

This will produce matches that include the separators along with capturing groups 1 through 6 for each byte of the MAC address.  The formatted MAC address can be composed from the capturing groups and a canonical separator.

The C# sample code to process the data looks like:

```
List<string> vectors = new List<string>();
vectors.Add("AABBCCDD11AA");
vectors.Add("AABB.CCDD.11AA");
vectors.Add("AB.BB.CC.DD.11.AA");
vectors.Add("AA.BB.CC.DD.11:AA   uselessText");
vectors.Add("UselessText AA.BB.CC.DD.11.AA   ");
vectors.Add("MoreText:AA,BB:CC.DD.11.AA");
vectors.Add("AA. BB. CC. DD. 11. AA");
vectors.Add("AA, BB, CC, DD, 11, AA   uselessText");
vectors.Add("UselessText.:AA:BB:CC:DD: 11: AA");
vectors.Add("MoreText:00.AA.BB.CC.DD.11.AA");
vectors.Add("Text00.00.00.00.00.00");
vectors.Add("ABAB ");
vectors.Add("There's nothing to match on this line");
vectors.Add("01010101010 textUslessText");

snippetResult.Clear();

Regex regex = new Regex("([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})(?:[:., ]*)([0-9A-F]{2})");
foreach (string vector in vectors)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(vector);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string mac
            = match.Groups[1].Value + ":"
            + match.Groups[2].Value + ":"
            + match.Groups[3].Value + ":"
            + match.Groups[4].Value + ":"
            + match.Groups[5].Value + ":"
            + match.Groups[6].Value;
        snippetResult.Text += "Match '";
        snippetResult.Text += match.Groups[0].Value;
        snippetResult.Text += "' ==> ";
        snippetResult.Text += mac;
        snippetResult.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

The output using your test vectors is:

```
Match 'AABBCCDD11AA' ==> AA:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match 'AABB.CCDD.11AA' ==> AA:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match 'AB.BB.CC.DD.11.AA' ==> AB:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match 'AA.BB.CC.DD.11:AA' ==> AA:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match 'AA.BB.CC.DD.11.AA' ==> AA:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match 'AA,BB:CC.DD.11.AA' ==> AA:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match 'AA. BB. CC. DD. 11. AA' ==> AA:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match 'AA, BB, CC, DD, 11, AA' ==> AA:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match 'AA:BB:CC:DD: 11: AA' ==> AA:BB:CC:DD:11:AA
Match '00.AA.BB.CC.DD.11' ==> 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:11
Match '00.00.00.00.00.00' ==> 00:00:00:00:00:00
```